# iTextSharp: Digital sign by smart Card ON on IIS EXPRESS but NOT on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, itext, digital-signature

my question concerns a .NET MVC5 app deployed on IIS7.
I've tried to digitally sign PDF documents by iTextSharp API, and it's OK when debugging in Visual studio (VS2013), but on IIS the program throws an exception:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Une erreur interne s’est produite.

   à System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
   à System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
   à System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
   à System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
   à System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()
   à ma.metl.reclamation.Service.Signature.PDFSignHelper.PDFSignDoc(String SrcPath, String DestPath) dans c:\Users\Jamal eddine\Desktop\Evolution SGI\SGI.RECLAMATION\SGI.RECLAMATION\ma.metl.reclamation.Service\Signature\PDFSignHelper.cs:ligne 186
   à ma.metl.reclamation.Service.ProcesVerbalService.GetFilePvSigne(String urlFilePv) dans c:\Users\Jamal eddine\Desktop\Evolution SGI\SGI.RECLAMATION\SGI.RECLAMATION\ma.metl.reclamation.Service\ProcesVerbalService.cs:ligne 267
```

My code:

```
avar store = new X509Store(StoreName.My);
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
_logger.Info("Nobre certif: " + store.Certificates.Count);

X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, CertName, false);

if (col.Count == 0)
    throw new Exception();


if (col.Count > 1)
{

    currentCert = col[1];
}

else
{

    currentCert = col[0];

}

Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser cp = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[]
{
    cp.ReadCertificate(currentCert.RawData)
};


var reader = new PdfReader(SrcPath);
var os = new FileStream(DestPath, FileMode.Create);
var stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');
// Creating the appearance
var appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
appearance.Reason = ConstantManager.SigningReason;
appearance.Location = ConstantManager.SigningLocation;
appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 100, 250, 150), 1, "sig");

if (currentCert.HasPrivateKey)
{
    var a = currentCert.PrivateKey;
}

IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(currentCert, "SHA-1");
// Creating the signature
MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
stamper.Close();
```

I've tried everything i found on google and other sites:

- Change the user of IIS appPool to my administrator.
- Give permissions to the folder machineKeys on Windows to grant IIS access to my privateKey.

PS: My certificate is not exportable so i can't even find the famous "manage Private Key" in MMC to grant my user access to the PK.

Comment: The manage private key option must be here. Are you sure then you gave the app pool account the access to the private key? Or even that you are looking at correct cert store? You are not specifying the cert location and thus the current user (app pool owner) store is used. Perhaps you assume some other store is queried here.

Comment: thank you for your reply. My certificate is in currentUser store. so i'm accessing to it from MMC in the currentUser store but by clicking right on it ==> All tasks, i didn't find manage private key. i think this is due to the fact that my private key is not exportable i guess.

Comment: You are accessing it from the "currentUser store". Are you sure the "currentUser" is the very same user your app pool account is using? People tend to confuse these two - they use "currentUser store" which is their own account's store rather than app pool user store. What I think possibly happens is that you have the sole certificate (without the private key) imported to your personal cert store while the app pool account has the same cert plus its private key imported to their cert store.

Comment: Thanks again. The user of appPool is the same connected (the currentUser). what confirms that, is the  fact that my program find the certificate and find the private key of it but when trying to read it, it throws the famous exception : if (currentCert.HasPrivateKey)
{
    var a = currentCert.PrivateKey;
}